# Dreams of a bible in another language

Tags: jewish-books

Good morning,
Thank you for taking the time to read this. I’m not Jewish. I grew up in a Pentecostal Church but as a child I had a dream in which I walked into a beautiful cathedral only to have everything in it become twisted and demonic including the pictures within a large beautiful bible. In the dream I ran out of the Church only to get trapped between an evil horde of demons and a ledge dropping into a river of fire. In the dreams I decided to jump into the fire rather than allow myself to be caught by the horde. As I fell towards the fire I was caught up by an open book which had writing I did not understand and seemed to be written in Hebrew. To this day the dreams still haunts me more than any nightmare I’ve ever had. At one point I thought of speaking to a rabbi and considered a change in religion. Looking for a different opinion. Any help is great appreciated.

Comment: On what basis where you able to determine that the book’s language “seemed to be written in Hebrew”? As a non-Jewish child, did you know the Hebrew alphabet?

Comment: I went through different languages and of the text I remember it matched Hebrew. I’d never even seen Hebrew text until years later.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. I'm  not really sure what your question is. Are you asking if you should change religions? Are you asking what the significance of seeing a Hebrew book in a dream is? You can clarify by [edit]ing the post to formulate a precise question.

Comment: Hi Serna, if you wish to discuss the Pentecostal Church and also the Jewish religion, with a Rabbi, feel free to write to me at davidariel25@gmail.com. This message board is not made for extended discussions which lead into comparative religion.

Comment: Serna, keep in mind that dreams are oftentimes just that - dreams, and not every one of them has significance even when we want to assign it such. I think that if you are interested in converting to Judaism based on this dream (as you have implied), you need to speak with a competent Orthodox rabbi. Might I suggest, though, looking into your own family history and checking to see if you aren't already Jewish? Just because you grew up Pentecostal doesn't mean you're not Jewish already. If your mother was Jewish, and her mother as well, then you are considered a full-fledged Jew.

Answer (score 3):

Good Evening,

I will answer your OP to the best of my ability according to what I think you are asking. Please feel free to edit your question by borrowing my wording.

**1) Should a person consider making an important life decision, based upon a message or feeling in a dream? What is the Jewish outlook on this?**

The Jewish tradition on dream interpretation says three things that may be of interest to you:

a) People tend to dream about things they thought of when they were awake.

b) Every dream has a measure of nonesense within it.

c) A dream can be a lower level kind of prophecy. It may be a message to you from your Creator to help you understand something.

These statements are to be found in the Talmud (Brachos: ch. 9 )

So, just because you have a dream, and even if a dream might be a message from Above for you; it is still not a basis for doing something like converting to a certain religion.

After all, a child's nightmare will contain nonesense, and may be the result of a day's worry which manifests in the form of familiar scenes in the child's mind from his or her cultural upbringing.

Practical life choices must be decided by reason and sincerity coupled with prayer and proper guidance.

But what if it is also a Divine message? Well, you can settle the agitation of your soul, by investigating a) Your current religion and b) Judaism, with an open mind, to see if you should consider making any changes.

Specific to the details in the dream you provided, the message ***may be***:

The current Church you are in and the people running it, are not giving you the best view of life. Examining the roots of your beliefs (by seeking out the Jewish sources for the Bible you accept) will bear fruit.

But in the end, use your G-d given talent and reason to be sincere, and investigate the truth. When you are convinced that a certain path is the fear of Heaven, then follow it, regardless of (or instead of) simply relying upon a perceived message in a dream. Even if the dream helped you to look, only rely in the end upon true reason when making a life choice.

As the verse says in Eccl. 5:6 (5:7 in Christian Bibles) "Even in the midst of **dreams**, futility, and many words (many things), fear G-d!"

Comment: @Serna you are most very welcome Serna